# Principled Volume not showing up in Cycles Render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, shaders, volumetrics

My Blender scene looks like this:
[image]

On the left, you can see my cloud-like volume setup. The center screen is in Material Preview mode and shows my clouds (the volumes) just right. As you can see in the Dimensions panel, the selected Cloud Box is actually pretty large (30x30x30m), but the clipping of my camera is already set to 1000m.

The problem is, that in my renders, the volumes seem just invisible. Whatever I'm doing, even if I change the cloud color to black, it doesn't ever show up in the Cycles render.

Is there a setting I'm missing?

---

**Update 1:**

After following suggestions, I removed most of the nodes. For testing purpopses, I even disconnected the noise texture:

[image]

This looks quite foggy in the preview now:

[image]

And indeed, in the render output, I can see *something*, but not what I've seen in the preview. The rear-half of the plane looks kindo of blue-ish. And when I disable the rendering of my "Cloud Domain" objects, the blue-ish look disappears. So it seeems to be there. Cycles just seems to treat those volumes substentially different compared to Eevee.

[image]

The weird background is a Sky Texture node with the 2.9 new Nishita mode. I set it to be that dirty, because I wanted to see a better contrast to the clouds while I'm testing. It's the only light source by the way.

I'd still guess that it has something to do with my Render settings or the how the ligthing is configured, but I don't know what exactly this could be.

Some more images:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: maybe share the volumetric cube? I suppose you've made it visible in render in the Outliner? We can't see the camera icon...

Comment: Thank you, I updated my question accordingly!

Comment: could you please just share a file with the cube you use? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Alright. My scene also contains an aircraft. Here's the blend file: https://pasteall.org/blend/b18cd43e6bed447d9d93cf6f319945c8

The cubes are at Z position 2177m. I duplicated many the cubes and most of them share the same material (at least the one visible from the camera do).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do any on the cubes overlap? Overlapping volumetrics can cause unexpected results.

Comment: I guess they don't. They all were duplicated using their exact dimensions (30x30x30m). So for example, I shifted one of the cubes on the X axis by 30m.

Comment: it works here; it takes just a lot of time to calculate, by the way we can't see your plane, I supposed it's a linked object in your original file?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. The plane got indeed linked into the file from the built-in Blenderkit addon. It's weird that it's working for you. I guess I should just try another method of creating clouds and not waste too much time on this. :(

Comment: There could be an issue with faces of adjacent cubes exactly overlapping.ie, 30cm cubes moved 30cm on X would mean each sharing a face in the exact same position. This can cause z-fighting issues and can cause Cycles to be unable to detect properly when a ray moves into or out of a volume. You could try moving them a fraction and see if that gives different results.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your material nodes, you are mixing a Surface Shader (Transparent BSDF) in with the volumetric - this may be the cause of your problems as the preview may behave differently to the actual render (especially with versions that support Eevee since the material preview will use Eevee to render while the actual render is using Cycles).

Generally you do not need to mix in 'transparency' with volumetric shaders - simply control the Density instead; ie, zero density is 100% transparent.

Try connecting the Principled Volume directly into the Volume socket of the Material Output and use the Noise Texture to vary the Density of the volume rather than to vary a mix shader.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It brought me a step further. However, I wasn't able to solve the whole problem. I updated my question accordingly. It would be nice if you could take a look at it again. Thanks!